# How to use Kendo UI Template to replace jQuery's AppendTo?

Tags: templates, kendo-ui

Now I am using jQuery's `AppendTo` method to add a string element to a div for the input:

```
var fixedpricePanelDiv = 
'<label class="control-label">Fixed price: </label>'
+'<input id="cakpriceNum" name="cakcommitprice[cakprice]" type="number"/>'
+'<input id="cakpriceunitidDdl" name="cakcommitprice[cakpriceunitid]" />';
$(fixedpricePanelDiv).appendTo($("#panel"));

<div id="panel"></div>
```

If I now change to KendoUI Template, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do the flowing

```
<div id="example"></div>
        <script>
            var template = kendo.template('<label class="control-label">Fixed price: </label>'+'<input id="cakpriceNum" name="#= cakprice#" type="number"/>'+'<input id="cakpriceunitidDdl" name="#= cakpriceunitid#" />');

            var data = { cakpriceunitid: "some val",cakprice:"some val" }; //A value in JavaScript/JSON
            var result = template(data); /Pass the data to the compiled template
            $("#example").html(result); //display the result
        </script>
```

More info Check the Doc http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Comment: Hi cwishva what I expect is without "var data" statement, which is pure like: var template = kendo.template('<label class="control-label">Fixed price: </label>'+'<input id="cakpriceNum" name=" cakprice" type="number"/>'+'<input id="cakpriceunitidDdl" name=" cakpriceunitid" />');   this will appear as an input field in the form without value. any further advice?

Comment: I'm confused , you need just two inputs to show in a form ? no values involved ?

Comment: in fact the scenario is like this, let's say I have an insert button, each click will provide a line of input label and box; the second scenario is I have a form, a part of the form will be reused by add button, let's say I have a vessel and its BL input, but the vessel will have several BL, so I will use a insert button to add a new line to input BL information.

Comment: @ cwishva Hi  cwishva, in fact what I care is not for data display template but data input template

Comment: Hi cwishva, kendo.View can be used to resolve my problem

Comment: great.Post your solution here

Answer (score 0):

Since the research from Kendo Document, I think kendo.view is used for this purpose